# font size affects the block element's height?

Tags: html, css

A block elements height is affected by the contents font size right?

It's best to just show you what I mean, look at this example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DtcFn/)

If you increase the font size of the class `.p` inside the div, the div's height increases too, why is this?

Comment: I believe that http://jsfiddle.net/DtcFn/6/ is a better fiddle in that I think it shows the changes that you are talking about. This hopefully will make it more obvious to people what changes and what resizing you are talking about.

Comment: yes.it describes the question more intuitively.thank you

Answer (score 9):

That's because the font size of the div decides where the base line for the text is, and the span is placed on that base line.

Increasing the font size of the div makes the distance above and below the base line higher. It's the content of the span inside that gives the element size, so it's only the distance above the base line that affects the size, not the distance below the base line, so you will be see text being pushed down, but there is no corresponding space below the text.

Comment: oh.thank you .if there are some documents about this .for example in the w3 document

Comment: how dose the font size decide the base line ?

Comment: @SKing7: The font size sets the text height, but the line height limits it. Put some characters outside the span to see how the font size and line height affects them: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/DtcFn/7/

Comment: the line-height limit the increasing,but why height increase a bit still?

Comment: @SKing7: The line height of the outer element limits its text height, but the inner element has a different line height, so its text height can be taller and affect the size of the outer element.

Comment: yes ,i find when the font size increase to about 35px.the height of the div class is p .why?why not the height of the inner element span??

Comment: @SKing7: It's complex as you have two sets of font sizes and line heights. The height of the div is at least the height of the span, but it can have extra space above and below. I added background color to the spans so that you see where they are: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/DtcFn/10/

Comment: i kown the extra space above and bolow.but i don't kown how does it caculate the size of the space above and below.

Comment: @SKing7: Most of it is in the CSS specification, but not all in the same place as it covers several different concepts. MOst of it is in chapters 9 and 10. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Comment: ok.i will read it .the lastest question:http://jsfiddle.net/DtcFn/12/,when i increase the line-height of p until to 18px .the height of div will be higher .ever,i thought that the height of div would change util 26px .that more bigger than 25px.

Answer (score 2):

**Because you have no set height on the div.**

This means the div will expand to fit its contents, in this case the `p` element.

If you do not specify a height it will default to `height:auto`.

Comment: but there is no element is affacted by the font-size of div of class name is p

Comment: Specifying a height for the div doesn't prevent the space above the text, it will only clip the text at that height.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you didn't define the `height`-property in the Stylesheets. Default is `height: auto`.

Comment: Specifying a height for the div doesn't prevent the space above the text, it will only clip the text at that height.

Comment: @Guffa: what does the space above have to do anything? The question was why is the height changing and the reason is that the height wasn't defined... What that height is taken up by is surely an entirely different issue?

Comment: @Guffa: Ah, I see what you mean, if you increase the font-size on the `p` class to above 33px then the div will get bigger but the font won't change. I had tried changing that value but not high enough so the only font size that I found that made a difference was the one that changes the text.

Comment: This increasing gap is because above `font-size: 33px` the `line-height` can't be `19px` anymore. So the line-height is increasing and with it the height of the box.

Comment: the line-height changes? why??

Comment: because the font is getting bigger.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set div height, see http://jsfiddle.net/VpeW8/

Comment: Specifying a height for the div doesn't prevent the space above the text, it will only clip the text at that height.

Answer (score 0):

Because line height is estimated according to font size. In order to stop the div from expanding in response to font size explicitly set the line-height property in CSS.